# Unable to communicate with the PayPal gateway

Tags: php, magento, paypal

here is my website: http://saffronflavor.com
I used magento v1.9.2.1,i set up my paypal setting well, sandbox is off, SSl is  off, all the privilege from paypal has been set.
But still im getting this error: Unable to communicate with the PayPal gateway
any help plz?

Thanks

```
here is the log:
2015-10-25T02:16:09+00:00 ERR (3):
exception 'Exception' with message 'PayPal NVP CURL connection error #7: ' in /home/www/saffronflavor.com/app/code/core/Mage/Paypal/Model/Api/Nvp.php:983
Stack trace:
#0 /home/www/saffronflavor.com/app/code/core/Mage/Paypal/Model/Api/Nvp.php(616): Mage_Paypal_Model_Api_Nvp->call('SetExpressCheck...', Array)
#1 /home/www/saffronflavor.com/app/code/core/Mage/Paypal/Model/Express/Checkout.php(381): Mage_Paypal_Model_Api_Nvp->callSetExpressCheckout()
#2 /home/www/saffronflavor.com/app/code/core/Mage/Paypal/Controller/Express/Abstract.php(108): Mage_Paypal_Model_Express_Checkout->start('http://saffronf...', 'http://saffronf...', true)
#3 /home/www/saffronflavor.com/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(418): Mage_Paypal_Controller_Express_Abstract->startAction()
#4 /home/www/saffronflavor.com/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(254): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('start')
#5 /home/www/saffronflavor.com/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(172): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#6 /home/www/saffronflavor.com/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(365): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#7 /home/www/saffronflavor.com/app/Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#8 /home/www/saffronflavor.com/index.php(83): Mage::run('', 'store')
#9 {main}
-------------------------------
2015-10-25T02:16:09+00:00 DEBUG (7): Array
(
[url] => https://api-3t.paypal.com/nvp
[SetExpressCheckout] => Array
(
[PAYMENTACTION] => Sale
[AMT] => 12.00
[CURRENCYCODE] => USD
[RETURNURL] => http://saffronflavor.com/index.php/paypal/express/return/
[CANCELURL] => http://saffronflavor.com/index.php/paypal/express/cancel/
[INVNUM] => 100000001
[SOLUTIONTYPE] => Mark
[GIROPAYCANCELURL] => http://saffronflavor.com/index.php/paypal/express/cancel/
[GIROPAYSUCCESSURL] => http://saffronflavor.com/index.php/checkout/onepage/success/
[BANKTXNPENDINGURL] => http://saffronflavor.com/index.php/checkout/onepage/success/
[LOCALECODE] => en_US
[ITEMAMT] => 7.00
[TAXAMT] => 0.00
[SHIPPINGAMT] => 5.00
[L_NUMBER0] => 1gpoushali
[L_NAME0] => 1.00 g Poushali Negin Saffron
[L_QTY0] => 1
[L_AMT0] => 7.00
[BUSINESS] => devpills
[NOTETEXT] =>
[EMAIL] => parham(removed)
[FIRSTNAME] => parham
[LASTNAME] => abbasi
[MIDDLENAME] =>
[SALUTATION] =>
[SUFFIX] =>
[COUNTRYCODE] => MY
[STATE] =>
[CITY] => cyberjaya
[STREET] => block 1 floor 8 unit 03A domain bulding cyberjaya selangor
[ZIP] => 54687954
[PHONENUM] => (removed)
[SHIPTOCOUNTRYCODE] => MY
[SHIPTOSTATE] =>
[SHIPTOCITY] => cyberjaya
[SHIPTOSTREET] => block 1 floor 8 unit 03A domain bulding cyberjaya selangor
[SHIPTOZIP] => 54687954
[SHIPTOPHONENUM] => (removed)
[SHIPTOSTREET2] =>
[STREET2] =>
[SHIPTONAME] => parham abbasi
[ADDROVERRIDE] => 1
[METHOD] => SetExpressCheckout
[VERSION] => 72.0
[USER] => ****
[PWD] => ****
[SIGNATURE] => ****
[BUTTONSOURCE] => Magento_Cart_Community
)
[response] => Array
(
)
[__pid] => 31604
)
```

Comment: I dont know much abt Magento but the line 'exception 'Exception' with message 'PayPal NVP CURL connection error #7: ' in /home/www/saffronflavor.com/app/code/core/Mage/Paypal/Model/Api/Nvp.php:983' explains that something is rong in Nvp.php on line 983.

Comment: yes, the reason for this msg is bkz there is no response from paypal, i also put the array that paypal gets, but response is null and empty

Comment: Is PayPal working with send box ?

Comment: Sagar, didnt try sandbox yet, i was testing on real paypal, sandbox is very slow, i created a sandbox account 2 weeks ago, i still waiting for their confirmation email !!!, thats why im not working on sandbox.

Comment: I find the solution, It was about Outgoing Connections which web hosting company was blocking it, after talking with support, they allowed Outgoing connections to paypal website. now its working.

Answer (score 0):

I find the solution, It was about Outgoing Connections which web hosting company was blocking it, after talking with support, they allowed Outgoing connections to paypal website. now its working.

Answer (score 0):

To solve this issue, you can follow these instructions as below:

**1. Disable SSL verification.**

You go to the Magento backend, then chooser `System-> Configuration-> Payment Methods` and find `PayPal Express Checkout`

You click to "`Configure`" button, then expand "`Advanced settings`" section and you'll see "`Enable SSL verification`" option that you need to disable. Let’s turn it to "No".
[view more..](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/103714/unable-to-communicate-with-the-paypal-gateway)